# a question regarding "when"

Tags: clauses

> Why does he steal things when he could easily afford to buy them?

What does “when” in the sentence mean? Does it mean “in what situation”?
Is “when he could easily afford to buy them” a time clause?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly. As snailboat says, it is the [sense 3 as mentioned in ODO:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/when)

> when - *In view of the fact that; considering that*

You may read it his way -- ***If*** he could easily afford to buy them, why does he steal things?

I think the use of *when* is quite closer to *while* in such context.

> Why does he steal things *while* he could easily afford to buy them?